# How to send mail from SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I started to use SQL for a few days, so I'm just a beginner.
I want to do the following: I want to run a query in every month, which gives back the data I need, then store it in an .xls file or something else, and then send it to some recipients. Can I do this fully automatically somehow in SQL Server 2005? Could someone give me an example or a guide how to do this? I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a SQL Server Agent [**job**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) that executes the [**sp_send_dbmail**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190307.aspx) stored procedure.

The results of the query can be included in the body of the e-mail message or attached as a file.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/reporting-services-features.aspx) and its subscriptions. They allow you to automatically send reports (results from queries ran against your DB) via email (in a PDF, HTML, XLS, etc. formats).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet to send a mail from the SQL server.

```
EXEC master..xp_sendmail
    @recipients = 'xxx@yyy.com',
    @subject = 'Hello from SQL team', 
    @message = 'A new mail has been sent.'
```

Also more information is found on these procedures in the below link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155737(office.10).aspx

Comment: Worth to remember, though, that `xp_sendmail` is obsolete - *This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. To send mail from SQL Server, use Database Mail.* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189505.aspx